# Rewrote url with htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong but I rewrote URL from

`system/?lnk=something` to `system/something` and it's working fine.

Now the problem is if I add another slash after like `system/something/` it still loads the page, but it seems to be without css, totally renders differently for some reason. Does anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Check your page for where you declare the location of your CSS.
Try using an absolute path (from the domain).
For instance..

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Would link to www.domain.com/css/mystyle.css regardless of what page you are on... However... If you put it like follows....

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Assume it was in the css folder, it would only work if you are in that folder.

So as your URL rewrite is making you a level deeper in the folder thus not linking correctly to the stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you! But is this the way things are usually handled? Or is there something else that can be done to prevent this even while going a level deeper or it just happens to everyone as for example twitter /this/name/hello.. example. Thanks!

Comment: well css doesn't move much so I would suggest a method like above always.